# IOS: reader for a PDF

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

In my app I want insert a pdf file for read it, the problem is that the pages of this pdf file are not simply A4 but it has square pages, and I want to simulate the browse of this pdf file (as a book) so I want to ask if is a better idea to use a pdf file or simply image (png) to simulate the browse of this file.

Look this example, it's a good idea.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/leaves

but I'm not able to have it in landscape and trasform it for my pdf size. Can you suggest me a simply way to browse a pdf file with square pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it look good, it'll probably be best that you edit all the pages to be the same size. That would mean that you'd embed your square pages in a presumably white background to make them rectangular like a normal book.

Then save the PDF (or whatever format is necessary) and use a control like the one you linked to.